# Apply chaining method calls in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, design-patterns

I would create a python class "ExcelFile" to handle adding multiple sheet in a workbook,

The function should be generic , so any one of the team could use it easily,

I did the developpement and everything is fine,my code is like :

```
def addSheet(df,"sheet_name1"):
    -- reading template
    -- add sheet1
    -- replace existing file
```

and after I call the function many times, it depends how much sheet i want to add,so:

```
addSheet(df1,"sheet_name1")
addSheet(df2,"sheet_name2")
addSheet(df3,"sheet_name3")
```

I want to refactor my code and put it into a python Class and implement a design pattern that will help me to do the job by calling

```
xls_file = ExcelFile().useTemplate("template_path").addSheet(df,"sheet_name1").addSheet(df2,"sheet_name2").writeXlsFile("filename")
```

What'is the name of the design pattern to do something like this?

Comment: You may call that fluid / fluent API - you can research that using google. SO is not a platform for colloborated programming, try to solve it and come back if you got specific problems.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, thanks for your response,I putted the solution afer searching,

Comment: This isn't really a common API design in Python.

Comment: @chepner , I thought first that is a design pattern like builder or factory, now, i get it

Comment: It is, but design patterns aren't universal. Some exist to make up for short comings in a particular language, though that's not the case here. AFAIK, the point of the builder pattern is that you can thread a partially built object through multiple function calls. It's not just so you can lump what could otherwise be a self-contained group of mutating method calls into a single giant expression. (Ideally, the builder wouldn't mutate any internal state either, but create a *new*, augmented builder at each step.)

Answer (score 1):

So after searching : 
I did the chain method

import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

```
class ExcelFile(object):
    template_path = None
    file_path = None
    book = None
    xlwriter = None

    def replaceSheet(self, dataframe, sheet_name):
        pandas_df = dataframe.toPandas()
        self.book = openpyxl.load_workbook(self.template_path)
        self.xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(self.template_path, engine='openpyxl')
        # test if the sheet doesn't exist
        sheet_id = self.book.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
        self.book.remove(sheet_id)
        self.xlwriter.book = self.book
        pandas_df.to_excel(self.xlwriter, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False, header=True)
        return self

    def useTemplate(self, template_path):
        self.template_path = template_path
        return self

    def writeFile(self, file_path):
        self.book.save(file_path)
        self.xlwriter.save()
        self.xlwriter.close()
        return file_path
```

Anf instead of calling the function many times , I call by :

```
xls_file = ExcelFile()
xls_file.useTemplate(template_path=templatepath) \
    .replaceSheet(dataframe=Sales_df, sheet_name="DB Sales") \
    .replaceSheet(dataframe=cost_df, sheet_name="DB COST") \
    .replaceSheet(dataframe=b2c_df, sheet_name="DB B2C") \
    .writeFile(file_path=local_tmp_file)
```